# PCM5102A: analog output level not what I expected?

Tags: dac, output, rms, level

I cannot achieve a 2.1 Vrms mentioned in their [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5102a.pdf) (pages 4 and 9). I can only output 1.04Vrms from the 1kHz source. Do I measure it wrong or this is what I should expect? Or maybe I get such measurements because it could possibly be a counterfeit chip?

[image]

PCM5102A schematic:
[image]

**Update:**

I tried to play different sine wave tone (0 dBFS) generated from [Audiocheck](http://audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php) and now I can see 1.88 Vrms and 5.64 Vpp when there is no load. Is this something I should expect? I'm playing this sound at the full volume over bluetooth since I use CSRA64215 chip as a source for PCM5102A. I also checked CSRA64215 config and it's output level is already set to max.

[image]

Comment: What's your code, bits, and schematic and test points?

Comment: And the link to the datasheet and page reference?

Comment: 2.1Vrms is 6Vpp @ 1kohm and you are getting 3Vpp  @ ?

Comment: @ErikFriesen updated the main post with the schematic. I did those measurements directly from OUTL/OUTR and GND nearby. By the way, what do you mean code & bits?

Comment: @Transistor updated the main post with the links and page references.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 i'm getting 3.14Vpp when there is no load. I get 2.16Vpp @ 1kohm and in a such scenario Vrms is even lower (713mV)

Comment: exactly half is suspicious of software coding error.  2.16V @ 1kohm is normal with 470 Ohm filter, so use 10k or 1M load

Comment: Where do you get that 1 kHz source from? What exactly are the digital samples?

Comment: @CL. first I used Signal Generator app, but now I tried to play the generated sine tone (0 dBFS) from here: https://www.audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php and now I can see 1.88 Vrms and 5.64Vpp when there is no load. It's better, but still far from the numbers in the datasheet

Comment: You have to use a source with known bits. For full scale output you need 24 bit signed, of course depending how you have your spi set up.

Comment: Output audio signal with digital square wave and probe I2S WCLK & DATA with scope. Looking at scope, you can see bits on DATA so you will know what the actual digital amplitude sent to the chip is. This will tell you if the issue is in the digital chain before your DAC.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to measure the full-scale output, you have to input a full-scale sine wave.

I do not know what signal generator app you used, but https://www.audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php certainly is buggy and does not generate a 0 dB FS waveform.

As far as I can see, https://www.wavtones.com/functiongenerator.php works correctly. (Even a 16-bit file will bring you to within 0.01 % of the limits.)

Comment: I got the same measurements even with this generator, but then I tried to generate the sine wave using Audacity and it does this job quite well - now I get 1.58 Vrms @1k and 1.91 Vrms @ 10k. I also monitored what the bluetooth module is outputting - for some reason it outputs -0.95dBFS, I checked everything in DSP chain and everything was already bypassed. But I think we can calculate Vrms like that: -0.95dBFS is 0.896396, so  1.91 Vrms @ 10k / 0.896396 = 2.13V. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, -0.95 dbFS is about 89.6 % of full scale.

Comment: @user1258202 - I suggest you try measuring the output with no  load at all. Since the IC depends on a charge pump to get a negative supply, it won't provide much output current. If you pay attention to the data sheet, you'll notice that it does not include a spec on load resistance, which suggests it doesn't intend to use one.